# Update a column value based on filter python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, string-matching

I have two datasets say df1 and df:

**df1**

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ids': [101,102,103],'vals': ['apple','java','python']})

   ids    vals
0  101   apple
1  102    java
2  103  python
```

**df**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TEXT_DATA': [u'apple a day keeps doctor away', u'apple tree in my farm', u'python is not new language', u'Learn python programming', u'java is second language']})

                       TEXT_DATA
0  apple a day keeps doctor away
1          apple tree in my farm
2     python is not new language
3       Learn python programming
4        java is second language
```

What I want to do is want to update the columns values based on filtered data and map the match data to the new column such that my output is

```
                       TEXT_DATA      NEW_COLUMN
0  apple a day keeps doctor away      101
1          apple tree in my farm      101
2     python is not new language      103
3       Learn python programming      103
4        java is second language      102
```

I tried matching using

```
df[df['TEXT_DATA'].str.contains("apple")]
```

is there any way by which i can do this?

Comment: How would you handle two keywords in the same entry? Like: "The python tries to eat an apple".

Comment: No this wont be a case in my data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
my_words = {'python': 103, 'apple': 101, 'java': 102}
for word in my_words.keys():
    df1.loc[df1['my_column'].str.contains(word, na=False), ['my_second_column']] = my_words[word]
```

Comment: This gives me error "ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values". IF possible you could me an output for this

Comment: Edited answer to remedy NaN values.

Comment: "my_words = {'python': 103, 'apple': 101, 'java': 102}
for word in my_words.keys():
    df.loc[df['TEXT_DATA'].str.contains(word, na=False), ['TEXT_DATA']] = my_words[word] " overwrites the value, it doesn't add another column

Comment: Output from your code  "  TEXT_DATA
0       101
1       101
2       103
3       103
4       102"

Comment: I edited the answer, but this is something you could really have researched yourself by looking at the answer for a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to extract the values in `df1['vals']`. Then, create a new column and add the extraction result to the new column. And finally, merge both dataframes.

```
extr = '|'.join(x for x in df1['vals'])
df['vals'] = df['TEXT_DATA'].str.extract('('+ extr + ')', expand=False)
newdf = pd.merge(df, df1, on='vals', how='left')
```

To select the fields in the result, type the column name in the header section:

```
newdf[['TEXT_DATA','ids']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53699012/3545273) of both dataframes and then select the relevant rows and columns.

```
tmp = df.assign(key=1).merge(df1.assign(key=1), on='key').drop(columns='key')
resul = tmp.loc[tmp.apply(func=(lambda x: x.vals in x.TEXT_DATA), axis=1)]\
                              .drop(columns='vals').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This give me error    'TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns''