# Get Sum of Every Time Two Values Match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My googleing has failed me, I think my main issue is im unsure how to phrase the question (sorry about the crappy title). I'm trying to find the total each time 2 people vote the same way. Below you will see an example of how the data looks and the output I was looking for. I have a working solution but its very slow (see bottom) and was wondering if theres a better way to go about this.

```
This is how the data is shaped

----------------------------------
event   person  vote
 1        a      y
 1        b      n
 1        c      nv
 1        d      nv
 1        e      y
 2        a      n
 2        b      nv
 2        c      y
 2        d      n
 2        e      n
----------------------------------

This is the output im looking for

----------------------------------
Person  a   b   c   d   e
   a    2   0   0   1   2
   b    0   2   0   0   0
   c    0   0   2   1   0
   d    1   0   1   2   1
   e    2   0   0   1   2
----------------------------------
```

---

### Working Code

```
df = df.pivot(index='event', columns='person', values='vote')

frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)

for person1, value in frame.iterrows():

    for person2 in frame:

        count = 0 
        for i, row in df.iterrows():

            person1_votes = row[person1]
            person2_votes = row[person2]

            if person1_votes == person2_votes:
                count += 1

        frame.at[person1, person2] = count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try look at your problem in different way

```
df=df.assign(key=1)
mergedf=df.merge(df,on=['event','key'])
mergedf['equal']=mergedf['vote_x'].eq(mergedf['vote_y'])
output=mergedf.groupby(['person_x','person_y'])['equal'].sum().unstack()
output
Out[1241]: 
person_y    a    b    c    d    e
person_x                         
a         2.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.0
b         0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
c         0.0  0.0  2.0  1.0  0.0
d         1.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
e         2.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

@Wen-Ben already answered your question. It bases on the concept of finding all possibilities of pair-wise `person` and count those having same `vote`. Finding all pair-wise is cartesian product (cross join). You may read great post from @cs95 on [cartesian product (CROSS JOIN) with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699012/performant-cartesian-product-cross-join-with-pandas/53699013#53699013)

In your problem, you count same vote per `event`, so it is cross joint per `event`. Therefore, you don't need adding helper `key` column as in @cs95 post. You may cross join directly on column `event`. After cross join, filter out those pair-wise person<->person having same `vote` using `query`. Finally, using `crosstab` to count those pair-wise.

Below is my solution:

```
df_match = df.merge(df, on='event').query('vote_x == vote_y')    
pd.crosstab(index=df_match.person_x, columns=df_match.person_y)

Out[1463]:
person_y  a  b  c  d  e
person_x
a         2  0  0  1  2
b         0  2  0  0  0
c         0  0  2  1  0
d         1  0  1  2  1
e         2  0  0  1  2
```