# Calculate distance a dataframe with UTM coordinates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, distance, utm

I have a huge `dataframe`. The structure data looks like this:

```
df
ID  Annotation  X           Y
A   Boarding    767513.9918 9425956.2571
A   Alighting   767154.1396 9427584.0004
B   Boarding    767450.5277 9432627.9543
B   Alighting   767495.0101 9426797.1772
C   Boarding    767648.9507 9426442.5497
C   Alighting   767037.0309 9428878.9032
........
```

The X and Y data used UTM coordinates. I want to calculate the distance between each ID boarding and alighting. My question is quietly similar but different to this question ([Distance matrix in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679894/distance-matrix-in-python-pandas)). My expected result looks like this:

```
result
ID  Anotation_1 X_1         Y_1         Anotation_2 X_2         Y_2      Dist
A   Boarding    767513.99   9425956.26  Alighting   767154.14   9427584.00  1667.05
B   Boarding    767450.53   9432627.95  Alighting   767495.01   9426797.18  5830.95
C   Boarding    767648.95   9426442.55  Alighting   767037.03   9428878.90  2512.02
    .......
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why is boarding and alightning values interchanged?

Comment: @anky_91 I edited again the question. Thank you.

Comment: The distance is a distance between two point location of an ID (person) which is boarding and alighting spot. I use UTM (universe transverse mercator) coordinates system https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738529/distance-between-two-points-in-utm-coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this, *assuming the input is clean and correct*, would be using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
df = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values[0:2,2:4].flatten()))  # (*)
df.columns=['X_1','Y_1','X_2','Y_2']
#df.reset_index()  # Uncomment if you want 'ID' as a column and not an Index
```

As for the other columns in your desired result: The `Anotation_1` and `Anotation_2` are always constant, so I didn't bother to include them. The `Dist` column -- well, you can calculate it now, given the new columns, or you could change the code above to calculate the distance already while traversing the numbers in step `(*)` above, thereby changing our code to something like: (here used dummy distance calculation, replace it with yours!)

```py
def my_func(pdf):
    return pd.Series([pdf.values[0,2], pdf.values[0,3], pdf.values[1,2], pdf.values[1,3],
                      np.sqrt((pdf.values[0,2]-pdf.values[1,2])**2+(pdf.values[0,3]-pdf.values[1,3])**2)  # <= your distance calculation goes here...
                     ])
df = df.groupby('ID').apply(my_func)
df.columns=['X_1','Y_1','X_2','Y_2','Dist']
#df.reset_index()  # Uncomment if you want 'ID' as a column and not an Index
```

---

Update: If you insist on including those constant columns, you can simply add them later like so: (*but why would you? especially if it's a large `DataFrame`...*)

```py
df['Annotation_1'] = 'Boarding'
df['Annotation_2'] = 'Alighting'
# And if you further insist on a specific ordering of the columns, you can go with:
df = df[['Annotation_1', 'X_1', 'Y_1', 'Annotation_2', 'X_2', 'Y_2', 'Dist']]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would pivot the dataframe:

```
result = df.pivot('ID', 'Annotation', ['X', 'Y'])
```

to get

```
                      X                          Y              
Annotation    Alighting     Boarding     Alighting      Boarding
ID                                                              
A           767154.1396  767513.9918  9.427584e+06  9.425956e+06
B           767495.0101  767450.5277  9.426797e+06  9.432628e+06
C           767037.0309  767648.9507  9.428879e+06  9.426443e+06
```

Then I would rename the columns and reindex:

```
ix = result.columns.to_frame()
result.columns = ix['Annotation'] + '_' + ix.iloc[:,0]
result = result.reindex(columns=['Alighting_X', 'Alighting_Y', 'Boarding_X', 'Boarding_Y'])
```

to get:

```
    Alighting_X   Alighting_Y   Boarding_X    Boarding_Y
ID                                                      
A   767154.1396  9.427584e+06  767513.9918  9.425956e+06
B   767495.0101  9.426797e+06  767450.5277  9.432628e+06
C   767037.0309  9.428879e+06  767648.9507  9.426443e+06
```

It is now easy to compute the distance:

```
result['Dist'] = np.sqrt((result.Alighting_X - result.Boarding_X)**2 + (result.Alighting_Y - result.Boarding_Y)**2)
```

to finally get:

```
    Alighting_X   Boarding_X   Alighting_Y    Boarding_Y         Dist
ID                                                                   
A   767154.1396  767513.9918  9.427584e+06  9.425956e+06  1667.045847
B   767495.0101  767450.5277  9.426797e+06  9.432628e+06  5830.946773
C   767037.0309  767648.9507  9.428879e+06  9.426443e+06  2512.023929
```

Comment: thank you, boarding xy and alighting xy is very clever.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
m=(df.assign(k=(df.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1).astype(str)).
        set_index(['ID','k']).unstack().sort_values(by='k',axis=1))
m.columns=m.columns.map('_'.join)
```

---

```
m=m.assign(Dist=np.sqrt((m.X_1 - m.X_2)**2 + (m.Y_1 - m.Y_2)**2))
print(m)
```

---

[image]