# Efficient way to compute difference of all rows in dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I am looking for efficient way to compute difference of all rows in dask dataframe(preferred) Or any efficient way in pandas df.I have huge file with millions of rows, it is taking like forever to compute this.. Below is example:

```
d = {'A': [5, 9, 15, 0, 2], 'B': [7, 6, 3, 1, 4], 'C': [8, 11, 2, 5, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5'])
print(df)
tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
row_pointer = 1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for i, r in df.iloc[row_pointer:].iterrows():
        tmp.loc['(' + index + ' - ' + i + ')'] = df.loc[index] - df.loc[i]
    row_pointer += 1
print(tmp)
```

Output:

```
 A  B   C
i1   5  7   8
i2   9  6  11
i3  15  3   2
i4   0  1   5
i5   2  4   3
         A   B   C
(i1 - i2)   -4   1  -3
(i1 - i3)  -10   4   6
(i1 - i4)    5   6   3
(i1 - i5)    3   3   5
(i2 - i3)   -6   3   9
(i2 - i4)    9   5   6
(i2 - i5)    7   2   8
(i3 - i4)   15   2  -3
(i3 - i5)   13  -1  -1
(i4 - i5)   -2  -3   2
```

Comment: you can easily get rid of one loop by using broadcasting: `df - df.iloc[i,:]` subtracts row I from the whole df. Just over all rows and just drop the all zeros row per frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use broadcasting to do all of the subtractions. Then subset after with `<` to get all unique combinations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = df.to_numpy()
res = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(arr[:, None]-arr), 
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.index]))
res = res[res.index.get_level_values(0) < res.index.get_level_values(1)]
```

---

```
print(res)

        0  1  2
i1 i2  -4  1 -3
   i3 -10  4  6
   i4   5  6  3
   i5   3  3  5
i2 i3  -6  3  9
   i4   9  5  6
   i5   7  2  8
i3 i4  15  2 -3
   i5  13 -1 -1
i4 i5  -2 -3  2
```

---

Likely not feasible with millions of rows. Alternatively remove one level of the loop:

```
from itertools import chain 

arr = df.to_numpy()
data = [(arr[i, None]-arr)[i+1:] for i in range(np.shape(arr)[0])]

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.index])
idx = idx[idx.get_level_values(0) < idx.get_level_values(1)]

res = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(data), index=idx)
```

Comment: Upvoted. This is definitely really fast. However, I guess it will take huge amount of memory on dataset of millions of rows :). +1

Comment: This is almost identical to my answer, but 2 minutes earlier.

Comment: Yup It is working for small dataset but for huge file, I am getting 'MemoryError'

Comment: Though the index creation will be slow. You can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699012/performant-cartesian-product-cross-join-with-pandas

Comment: @ALollz  memory error again on line chain.from_iterable(data), therefore looking for dask, if it is possible to use distributed computing for such tasks.

Comment: @Manvi honestly I don't think that's really going to solve your problem. With even just 3M rows you have 3M Choose 2 (4.5 Trillion) rows in your output. This is an enormous calculation. Memory constraints will add serious time and complexity, given if you chunk the data you then need to ensure all pairwise combinations across chunks.

Comment: @ALollz yup agree, I have understanding that dask (https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) handles chunking and its memory management.

Comment: It does, but I think it gets complicated when things need to be done across chunks, which is the case here.

Comment: @ALollz I used Dask array and used lazy computation to get output. It looks like its doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

I used dask array to get output:

```
arr = df.to_numpy()
x = da.from_array(arr, chunks=(100))
diff = abs(x[:, None] - x)
diff[0:1000].compute()
diff[1000:2000].compute()
diff[2000:3000].compute()
```

I used Dask lazy computation to generate result for larger than memory arrays.