# From n x k DataFrame, generate a (n over 2) x 2k DataFrame of all pairs of rows

Tags: pandas, numpy, matrix, reshape

Given a pandas DataFrame x of dimensions n x k, how can we **efficiently** generate a DataFrame y of dimensions (n over 2) x 2k, whose rows are all possible combinations of rows pairs of rows from x?
For example, if x is

```
[[1 11],
 [2,22],
 [3,33],
 [4,44]]
```

then y should be

```
[[1,11,2,22],
 [1,11,3,33],
 [1,11,4,44],
 [2,22,3,33],
 [2,22,4,44],
 [3,33,4,44]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try `combinations`

```
from itertools import combinations
[*map(lambda x : sum(x,[]),combinations(l,r=2))]
Out[80]: 
[[1, 11, 2, 22],
 [1, 11, 3, 33],
 [1, 11, 4, 44],
 [2, 22, 3, 33],
 [2, 22, 4, 44],
 [3, 33, 4, 44]]
```

Comment: You probably meant `[*map(lambda x: sum(x,[]), itertools.combinations(x.values.tolist(),r=2))]`? Thank you! : )

Answer (score 1):

My attempt

```
l=[[1,11], [2,22], [3,33], [4,44]]
```

Full list

```
#lst=[x+y for x in [z for z in l[:3]] for y in [z for z in l[1:]] if x!=y]#Use + in list comprehension
```

If you wanted to eliminate `[3, 33, 2, 22]`. initialize a  new `list` and append `x+y` only if `y+x` doesn't exist.

```
k=[]
lst=[k.append(x+y) for x in [z for z in l[:3]] for y in [z for z in l[1:]] if x!=y if y+x not in k]
print(k)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By modifying Bharath's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699012/performant-cartesian-product-cross-join-with-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1), I produced a solution:

```
n=4; x=pandas.DataFrame([[i,11*i] for i in range(1,n+1)],columns=['A','B'])
cnct=( lambda l,i=0: pandas.concat(l,axis=i) )
z=cnct([ cnct([x.iloc[:i] for i in range(n)]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True), 
         cnct([x.iloc[i+1:] for i in range(n)]).reset_index(drop=True) ], 1)
```

For n=10**4, it outperforms the itertools solution.