# Replicating each record of one column for every record of second column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets with different lengths and I want to combine them such that:

| Amazon |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |

And

| Google |
| --- |
| x |
| y |
| z |

Combine together to give result:

| Amazon | Google |
| --- | --- |
| a | x |
| a | y |
| a | z |
| b | x |
| b | y |
| b | z |
| c | x |
| c | y |
| c | z |

Comment: This may help: [Performant cartesian product (CROSS JOIN) with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699012/performant-cartesian-product-cross-join-with-pandas)

Comment: If you have a older version of pandas you could try to play with explode.