# Merge Datasets by Group in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have the two datasets below and would like to merge them by group in df2. I am not sure how to merge them such that the dates reset for each group (ie. start from the 1st date and end at the last date for each group).

df1:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2021-01-01 |
| 2021-01-02 |
| 2021-01-03 |

df2:

| Group |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

dfdesired:

| Date | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A |
| 2021-01-02 | A |
| 2021-01-03 | A |
| 2021-01-01 | B |
| 2021-01-02 | B |
| 2021-01-03 | B |
| 2021-01-01 | C |
| 2021-01-02 | C |
| 2021-01-03 | C |

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699012/performant-cartesian-product-cross-join-with-pandas

Comment: It did work but quick question about it

Are those two different steps in the accepted answer or two different ways to do it entirely. I am talking about the "pandas <= 1.1.X`" and "pandas <= 1.2.X"

I ran them both and they gave me the same output.

Comment: If both versions of the code worked, then you're on the newer pandas 1.2.X distribution, so either will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform cross join. Here is what I would suggest:

```
# Creating a dummy column to perform a join
df1["Dummy"] = 1
df2["Dummy"] = 1

# to obtain the cross join we will merge on the dummy column and drop it.
df_desired= pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='Dummy').drop("Dummy", 1)
```